# RuntimeError: You must compile your model before using it

Tags: python-3.x, keras, compiler-errors, model, resnet

I try to run this code but I have this error, even after compiling my model:

> RuntimeError: You must compile your model before using it.

How can I fix this?

```
model = ResNet50(include_top=True, weights='imagenet')
model = Model(input=model.input,output=model.layers[-1].output) 
model.summary()
model = Sequential()
sgd = optimizers.SGD(lr=0.01, decay=1e-6, momentum=0.9, nesterov=True)
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=SGD(lr=0.01, momentum=0.9), metrics=   ['binary_accuracy'])
data_dir = "C:\\Users\\"
batch_size = 32
from keras.applications.resnet50 import preprocess_input
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
image_size = IMAGE_RESIZE
def append_ext(fn):
return fn+".jpg"
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join
dir_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
train_dir_path = dir_path + '\data'
onlyfiles = [f for f in listdir(dir_path) if isfile(join(dir_path, f))]

NUM_CLASSES = 2

from tensorflow.python.keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping, ModelCheckpoint

cb_early_stopper = EarlyStopping(monitor = 'val_loss', patience = EARLY_STOP_PATIENCE)
cb_checkpointer = ModelCheckpoint(filepath = '../working/best.hdf5', monitor = 'val_loss',       save_best_only = True, mode = 'auto')

from sklearn.grid_search import ParameterGrid
param_grid = {'epochs': [5, 10, 15], 'steps_per_epoch' : [10, 20, 50]}

grid = ParameterGrid(param_grid)

for params in grid:
    print(params)
from keras.optimizers import SGD
learning_rate = 0.1
sgd = SGD(learning_rate)
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',optimizer=sgd,metrics=['binary_accuracy'])

fit_history = model.fit_generator(
    train_generator,
    steps_per_epoch=STEPS_PER_EPOCH_TRAINING,
    epochs = NUM_EPOCHS,
    validation_data=validation_generator,
    validation_steps=STEPS_PER_EPOCH_VALIDATION,
    callbacks=[cb_checkpointer, cb_early_stopper])
model.load_weights("../working/best.hdf5")
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to write a hybrid between [Sequential API](https://keras.io/models/sequential/) and [Functional API](https://keras.io/getting-started/functional-api-guide/).

Don't :)

Be advised that your line `model = Sequential()` initializes a new model (using the Sequential API) and places it in `model`.

Your new model has no architecture and is not complied (the model you assigned to `model` is gone by this point).

Comment: There are two ways to build and extend Keras models - via the Sequential API and via the Functional API.

I would suggest opening these links and reading more.  

`model = Sequential()` intializes a new model using the Sequential API. 
When you do it you effectively render the previous assignments to `model` meaningless.

I extended the answer with this information.

Comment: You are welcome.
I think this may constitute a new question. please write the entire error message when you ask it.

If you were satisfied with my answer, I would kindly ask you to `accept` it.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Right now I have this error : ValueError: Could not interpret optimizer identifier: <tensorflow.python.keras.optimizers.SGD object at 0x0000019CE6152160>.  Note that : now I am using just a sequential model. Please, let me know if you have any suggestions. Thanks

Comment: I kindly suggest that you open a new question for this.
Comments are not meant to be used for discussing new questions, as it would be difficult for future users to find them.